# pass id to jquery modal form

Tags: php, jquery

i have following table where i am showing data from database. when i click edit button a dialog appear, there i need to show data in text boxes from db. but for getting data from db i need player_id in modal from.

```
<td><?php echo $player_id ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details; ?></td>
<td><button id="update_user">Edit</button></td>
```

so here i want to pass player_id to jquery modal form, where i can get data from db on the base of player_id for that specific player and show in text boxes and then again update to db.

```
<div id="update-form" title="Update Employee">

    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="player_id" id="player_id" value="$player_id" />
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="$name"/>
          <label for="details">Details</label>
    <input type="text" name="details" id="details" value="$details"/>
```

i want to pass $player_id variable to jquery Modal form. that's all.

Comment: How are you displaying the Modal form? If it is loaded via ajax, `$.post` the id to your php script and then include it in the form.

Comment: by clicking when click on edit button. modal form opens

Comment: Can you post the code to open the Modal form?

Comment: $( "#update-form" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   height: 500,
   width: 450,
   modal: true,
  });
   
   $( "#update_user" )
   .button()
   .click(function() {
    $( "#update-form" ).dialog( "open" );
   });

Comment: are you only showing one player ? or do you have multiple players in the table ? (if the later is the case you should use class="update_user" not id="update_user")

Comment: i have multiple players to show.

Comment: my only purpose is to pass $player_id variable to modal form when i click on edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<td><?php echo $player_id ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details; ?></td>
<td>
    <button class="update_user" data-payer_id="<?php echo $player_id ?>">Edit</button>
</td>

<script>
$(".update_user").click(function(){
    var player_id = $(this).attr('data-payer_id');
    $("#update-form").find("#player_id").val(player_id);
    $("#update-form").dialog("open");
});
</script>
```

PS: player_id should be a hidden field in the dialog form unless it is editable.