# Pass ID of button to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this [pass id to jquery modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198085/pass-id-to-jquery-modal-form) but seeing as I'm not too jQuery-savvy and I don't know PhP I'm not sure how I would implement this in my example.

My goal is to be able to pass the ID of a button, upon being pressed, to a form. Something like this:

```
<button id="dynamic_id">
<form id="time_form" action="{% url 'event' pk='button_id' %}" method="post">
# Lots of stuff
</form>
```

The `button_id` is where I'd like the button's ID to be.

I thought of something like

```
function getId(button_id) {
    document.getElementById('time_form').action = "{" + "%" + "url " + "event" + ' pk="' + button_id + '" %" + "}"';
}

<button id="dynamic_id" onClick="getId(this.id);">

<form id="time_form" action=""> (...)
</form>
```

But this does not work. I get an error message

```
400 Bad Request: Your browser semt a request this server cannot understand
```

UPDATE

I'm not trying this:

```
function getId(button_id) {
    var vk_input = document.CreateElement("input");
    vk_input.name = "vk_id";
    vk_input.value = button_id;
    vk_input.type = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("time_form").appendChild(vk_input);
}
```

But it does not work for some reason. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The request cannot be fulfilled probably due to bad syntax. Have you checked your console for when the error occurs?

Comment: Nothing is passed to the console unfortunately

Comment: However the URL that results is http://tbg/verkefni/%7B%%20url%20%22event%22%20pk=%2210%22 which is not what I want (though it has the correct button id, which is nice). The brackets and the % is Django code, not something HTML is supposed to try to parse.

Comment: Django will render on page load, including that in your JS function. So your `button_id` will not be what you think it is.

Comment: Oh. I'm out of ideas then. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dynamic_id').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var array_ids = [];
        $('.dinamics').each(function(){
            //console.log('gdfg');
            array_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        for(var i = 0; i < array_ids.length; i++){
            $('#time_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="your_button_id_'+i+'" value="'+array_ids[i]+'"/>')
        }
        $('#time_form').submit();
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, I've built on your answers and come up with something of my own, but it doens't work - can you take a look at it? (in Original post)

Comment: change CreateElement to createElement  - (syntax)

Comment: Great! Good catch. Thanks. Marking your answer as Answered because my problem is solved with your help

Answer (score 0):

How aboout this with jquery.

```
<button id="dynamic_id">
<form id="time_form" action="" method="post">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dynamic_id').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        $('#time_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="your_button_id" value="'+id+'"/>')
        $('#time_form').submit();
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Nice first answer! :D

Comment: This looks good, but the button ID is truly dynamic. There are multiple buttons like this with differing IDs that the function needs to be able to handle

Comment: sure, you can use jquery.each(), adding the same class to all buttons, then a loop to add to form.

Answer (score 0):

Button id passed correctly to `getId()` but generated string does not seems valid, here is some issue with quotes. See reduced example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmf1ysk7/)

try this:

```
document.getElementById('time_form').action = "{" + "%" + "url " + "event" + ' pk="' + button_id + '" ' + "%" + "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use jquery, is better an clean.
this is what you want?

```
<button id="dynamic_id" class="dinamics">Lots of stuff</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_1" class="dinamics">1</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_2" class="dinamics">2</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_3" class="dinamics">3</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_4" class="dinamics">3</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_5" class="dinamics">3</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_6" class="dinamics">3</button>
<button id="dynamic_id_7" class="dinamics">3</button>
<form id="time_form" action="" method="post">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dynamic_id').click(function(){
        var array_ids = [];
        $('.dinamics').each(function(){
            array_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        for(var i = 0; i < array_ids.length; i++){
            $('#time_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="your_button_id_'+i+'" value="'+array_ids[i]+'"/>')
        }
        $('#time_form').submit();
    })
})
</script>
```